# writing files in a subdirectory to a csv file and save it to parent directory in linux command line

Tags: linux, csv

I have a directory called 'dir', and there is a subdirectory in it called 'subdir'. Subdir has many files in it. I would like write to list of these files on a CSV file and save it to in 'dir' directory with a command line on linux. My code creates the csv file but saves it in subdir but not dir. Where do I do wrong? I am in dir directory;

```
dir$ ls subdir >names.csv
```

Comment: oh, that is typo thanks for noticing that, yes i have that > sign to save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should achieve it by using the **for** loop.

If my understanding is right, you want to get a list of files in the subdir. So do something like this:

```
$ cd dir
$ for files in subdir/*;do echo $files|cut -d '/' -f 2 >>filelist.csv;done
```

Now, you can see there is a file called "filelist.csv" has been created under your dir directory.

Comment: Well, new problem, now i have 5 subdirs in a dir directory, so there are subdir1 subdir2..subdir5. How can i write file list from all subdirs to one csv file and save it to dir?

Comment: @kutlus You need to state that in your question from the beginning so that what you need is clear rather than waiting until after an answer has been given.

Comment: @kutlus Yes, simply change "subdir/*" to "subdir*/*".

Answer (score 2):

As an easier alternative you could cd to subdir and use

```
printf "%s\n" * >../list.csv
```

This will give you a newline separated and newline terminated list with no commas involved. You can see it as a degererated csv file with only one column.

If you want to include hidden files (files with names that begin with a dot), you can use `* .*` instead of the sole `*`. If you want to exclude the . and .. directory names, use `* .[^.]* ..?*` instead. In total:

```
printf "%s\n" *             >../list.csv   # For non-hidden files.
printf "%s\n" * .*          >../list.csv   # For all files.
printf "%s\n" * .[^.]* ..?* >../list.csv   # For all files but `.` and `..`.
```

But keep in mind that filenames in Linux may contain newlines by themselves. In fact, the only unique single byte separator for filenames is the null byte.

*Update due to [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494943/writing-files-in-a-subdirectory-to-a-csv-file-and-save-it-to-parent-directory-in/494948#comment909762_494946):*

Let us assume that you have any number of subdirs whose non-hidden contents you want to catalog in separate files in the common parent directory. (Collecting all names in one file is much shorter, see [this elegant solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494953/320385). And, to tell the truth, I have not read your comment carefully enough.) This can be achieved in that parent directory (dir in your case) by

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'cd {}; printf "%s\n" * >../$(basename {}).csv' \;
```

This requires the programs `find`, `bash`, and `basename`.

Using it you should take extra care, that dir does not contain files whose names conflict with the automatically generated csv lists.

Here is how it works: `find` considers each file that lies exactly one directory level below the current directory (`.`)—that is what `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` does—: If it is a directory (`-type d`) it executes (`-exec`) the command between `-exec` and the trailing `\;` after substituting the empty braces (`{}`) by the name of that directory. If we denote this name by `<SUBDIR>`, this results in

```
bash -c 'cd <SUBDIR>; printf "%s\n" * >../$(basename <SUBDIR>).csv'
```

This starts `bash` in a subprocess, causing it to execute the argument of the `-c` option as a shell script, namely

```
cd <SUBDIR>;
printf "%s\n" * >../$(basename <SUBDIR>).csv
```

which is pretty much the same as above. Here, the expression

```
$(basename <SUBDIR>)
```

is expanded to the basename of `<SUBDIR>`. This is necessary because `<SUBDIR>` will iterate through ./subdir1, ./subdir2, etc in your case. The corresponding basenames are subdir1, subdir2, etc.