# writing file names from subdirectories to a csv file in linux

Tags: linux, csv

Previously I have asked a very similar question but it was only for one subdirectory [writing files in a subdirectory to a csv file and save it to parent directory in linux command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494943/writing-files-in-a-subdirectory-to-a-csv-file-and-save-it-to-parent-directory-in). 
I have a directory called 'dir', and there are 5 subdirectories in it, sub1, sub2,..sub5. Each sub directory has many files in it. I would like write to list of files from all subdirectories to a CSV file and save it to in 'dir' directory with a command line on linux. My code does that except I only want the filenames (name1,name2 etc) but it writes the full filenames with path (./sub1/name1,./sub1/name2, etc ). The command line I am using inside the dir folder is;

```
dir$ find . -type f  > names.csv
```

Comment: See also the update to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494948/320385). It is not exactly what you want, but it is related: It gathers the file names of each sub-directory in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir$ find . -type f -execdir basename {} \; > names.csv
```

### Explanation

- `-execdir` performs the following command for each result.
- `basename {} \;` remove the part before the final `/`. The `{}` substitutes for each directory found. See `man find` for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Since you've tagged your question 'Linux', I assume you have GNU `find` - in which case you can use

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' > names.csv
```

From `man find`:

> ```
>           %f     File's  name  with  any leading directories removed (only
>                  the last element).
> ```

Comment: +1 this is much more elegant. I was not previously familiar with `-printf` in `find`.

Comment: thank you steeldriver for the great solution, since I already accepted the previous answer, I voted for you.